# Кастомная навигация Swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть слайдер swiper и есть список элементов, которые состоят из заголовка и текста. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике на каждый из элементов этого списка менялся слайд. Подскажите, как можно реализовать такое поведение.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Desc</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Desc</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Desc</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```